# TLS termination behind AWS ELB on HAProxy (tcp mode)

Tags: ssl, load-balancing, mqtt, haproxy, amazon-elb

I am using AWS ELB as entry point (in Proxy mode) to load balance among 2 HAProxy-es behind it from where traffic goes further to MQTT broker.

1. Those 2 HAProxies are responsible for client TLS termination (2 way TLS).
2. Certificates kind of work. I've tested on local setup between 2 servers. I've been able to publish with 2-way TLS, properly terminate it, and publish message to mqtt. Problem arise when moving everything to AWS.
3. I am using self signed root CA, intermediate CA, server certificate and client certificates. Using Elliptic Curve...
4. Problem might be due to a servers CN. I think it has to be the same as hostname connecting to with tools like mosquitto_pub.
5. Error that I get is TLS error, whith debug -> ssl handshake failure. Somehow I am not able to produce more verbose errors. Using openssl with s_client and debug for max debug output. Which produce me ssl handshake failure.

I would really appreciate any hint/suggestion.

Thanks in advance.

Tomaz

Comment: AWS ELB and Haproxy provide very similar functionality. What is your reason for using both? Why not have the ELB go straight to the MQTT server? Also I can't see the error message that you are referring to - there isn't a lot of go on?

Comment: @njh the motivation is probably what OP is referring to as "2-way TLS" -- authenticating of the client's cert by the back-edd.  ELB doesn't support this directly, it has to be in transparent TCP mode and let the back-end (HAProxy in this case) handle the TLS.

Comment: Yes, the CN in the server's cert has to match the hostname that the client uses to access the server.  You also need to have *no* cert on the ELB.  You sould probably temporarily remove ELB from the mix so that you are only troubleshooting one thing at a time.

Comment: The reason for using both is in fact that AWS ELB doesn't support Client side certificate termination. When refering to 2-way TLS I mean the setup where you use TLS on server side and with that client side certificates too for authentication. So I use ELB to round robin traffic to 2 or (n) HAProxies which knows how to terminate client certificates. I can't figure it out how to set/prepare certificates which reside on HAProxy (or n of them) that would satisfy this hostname and CN. Clients only know for ELB domain name. Behind I have ha1.domain.com, ha2.domain.com. How to solve this with CN?

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by using subjectAltName feature. I edited openssl.cnf and add new section [alt_names] and reference it later on in configuration. Under alt_names I added 1 DNS key, and 2 IPs. Found with `man x509v3_config`.

Best,
Tomaz